# Is it possible to change the bottom layout guide y position?

Tags: ios

I would like to move the content of the whole screen up to make room for a view that I would add to the main window. Is it possible to adjust the bottom layout guide y coordinate, and make the whole view structure move up?

thanks.

ios8+

Answer (score 0):

You can create an outlet to the bottom constraint of the view, and change its value from your code. `UIView` animations works fine in this case :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.verticalBottomConstraint.constant = 44
)
```

---

Yep, the `constant` property of a `NSLayoutConstraint` is variable while the `multiplier` property is constant. Logic everywhere.

Comment: thanks. Yes. What I need though is to affect any screens.. so that whole app changes the size.. not just the current screen. Any screen that I push etc.

Comment: You can embed your `UINavigationController` within an `UIViewController` using a container view. By changing the bottom constraint of this view, the view controller height will change and the pushed view controllers will adopt this new frame.

Comment: I've added an example project for you : https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg4cg739xe1ogug/testEmbed.zip?dl=0

Comment: I solved the problem by adjusting the size of the container view as you said. Thanks for the sample project also.
Will upvote you on the comment. In general I would still be curious if the bottom layout guide could be adjusted.

Comment: My guess is you can't adjust the bottom layout guide, but to be honest I'm not sure ;)